# How to define further commonparameters for powershell functions defined within a bespoke module?

Tags: powershell, refactoring, powershell-2.0, powershell-module

I'm writing a powershell module to interact with AWS.  Most of the functions need to take parameters that are the credentials to use - `awsAccessKeyId`, `awsSecretKey` and `credentialsFile`.

It's getting dull copy/pasting those parameters to each function in the module.

**Is there a way to declare that these are `CommonParameters` for the set of functions that the module exports?**

**Also, is there a way to extract the common (ie, duplicated) parameter-set handling switch-statement so it can be called by all the functions that need it?**

Here's an example function:

```
function New-S3Client {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParametersetName="credentialsFile")]
    param
    (
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName="specifyKey")] [string]$accessKey,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true, ParameterSetName="specifyKey")] [string]$secretKey,
        [parameter(ParameterSetName="credentialsFile")] [string]$credentialsFile = "$env:USERPROFILE\.aws\credentials"
    )
    switch($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName)
    {
        "specifyKey" {
            $env:awsAccessKeyId = $accessKey
            $env:awsSecretKey = $secretKey
            break
        }
        "credentialsFile" {
            $env:awsAccessKeyId = Read-ValueForKeyFromFile -from $credentialsFile -field AWSAccessKeyId
            $env:awsSecretKey = Read-ValueForKeyFromFile -from $credentialsFile -field AWSSecretKey
            break
        }
    }
    $config = New-Object Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Config
    $config.WithServiceURL("https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com")
    $client = New-Object Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Client($env:awsAccessKeyId, $env:awsSecretKey, $config)
    return $client
}
```

I would like to extract parameters 2-4 inclusive to `CommonParameters`, and then the switch block to some common function.

Answer (score 0):

Most modules I've come across use a Connect-SomeService function and then handle the connections/credentials within the module state. Maybe with some parts of it exposed in the callers session (array variable keeping track of connections).

Like VMware PowerCLI...

[Connect-VIServer](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/PowerCLI501/html/Connect-VIServer.html)

[Get-VM](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/PowerCLI501/html/Get-VM.html)

This way you only request credentials in a Connect-S3Service function. That command saves the connection in a variable that all your other functions use by default. However doing it this way mean you'll still want to have a $S3Service Common Parameter in all your other functions (incase you want to send jobs only to a specific connection), but atleast thats two parameters fewer.